# Websphere deployment application name

Tags: java, war, websphere-8, manifest.mf

When doing WAR deployment on IBM Webspehere 8.5 it is possible to set  *Application name* and *Application Build ID*

By default *Application Name* is the WAR filename and *Application Build ID* is set to *Unknown*.

I know i can set *Application Build ID* using `MANIFEST.MF` attribute *Implementation-Version*.

Is there any `MANIFEST.MF` attribute that is understood by WAS as *Application Name* or there is another way to achieve my goal?

*Application-Name* and *Implementation-Title* seem ignored by WAS.

Comment: I also have the same question. Is there any entry that we can do in the ibm-web-ext.xml or ibm-web-bnd.xml file?

Comment: Sorry, I have not found a solution yet...

Comment: Application build ID returns the build version from Manifest. This cannot be updated from Websphere as its a read-only field. 
However, Application name can be changed at the time of deployment from admin console, or using "appname" option for wsadmin scripting.
Refer: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html for more details